# Input validation for binary to decimal converter

Tags: java

I have to create binary to decimal number converter for an assignment. There are restrictions to this assignment. They are:
1.No infinite loops
2.Break statements to exit loops
3.No labels or go-to statements
4.No using Integer.parseInt (String s, int radix)

I got the part conversion down, but I am having trouble with exception handling. I am trying to have an error message display when input is not binary and continue allowing the user to input, displaying the same error message with each invalid attempt.

I have tried to replace the for loop with while and do-while loops, but it ended up being too confusing for me.

I also tried nesting an if statement in the for loop, but couldn't figure out how to implement userInput to continue having the user enter inputs after the the error message pops up.

```java
long binaryNumber = 0, baseTen = 0;     
String userInput;                       
int i;  
boolean okay;
                                                        
//Asks user to input binary number
        System.out.println("Enter a binary number.");
        userInput = in.nextLine();
                    
            for (i = 0; i <= userInput.length() - 1; i++) {
                char digit = userInput.charAt(i);
    
                //Checks if characters other than 1 or 0 is present
                if ((digit != '1') || (digit != '0') {
                    System.err.println("Try again");
                    okay = false;
                }
                //Converts binary to decimal
                if (digit == '1') {
                    binaryNumber += Math.pow(2, (userInput.length() - i)) / 2;
                    okay = true;
                } else if (digit == '0') {
                binaryNumber += 0;
                    okay = true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd use another `else` statement then you can set `okay` to false and check the value of `okay` after the for loop, and *the whole* procedure again after printing an error message. Of course, after setting `okay` to false you can break and stop parsing the input.

You could also throw an exception instead of setting `okay` to false and breaking, catch the exception and then restart the procedure from a higher level method. However, the user entering invalid data should probably *not* count as exceptional; you should always expect erroneous input.

Comment: I think I made a mistake by calling it exception handling (still a newbie to programming). I'll change the title to make it more fitting.